# Lines represented as long thin triangles are not visble in 3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am trying to draw a 3D line in wpf and I have this xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D x:Name="ViewerViewport"
                RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                Focusable="True" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Model">

        </ModelVisual3D>

        <!-- Camera -->
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="Camera"
                               Position="0,0,0"
                               LookDirection="0,1,0"
                               UpDirection="0,0,1"
                               FieldOfView="100"
                               FarPlaneDistance="10"
                               NearPlaneDistance="0.1"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

    </Viewport3D>

</Grid>
```

and this c# code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        var ModelsGroup = new Model3DGroup();
         ModelsGroup.Children.Add(this.AddLine(new Point3D(0, 0, 100), new Point3D(0, 100, 100),"line 1)"));
         ModelsGroup.Children.Add(new AmbientLight(Colors.White));
        Model.Content = ModelsGroup;
}
```

and line creation code:

```
  private Model3D AddLine(Point3D startPoint, Point3D EndPoint, string name)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        var material = new DiffuseMaterial(brush);
        var mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
        mesh.Positions.Add(startPoint);
        mesh.Positions.Add(EndPoint);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
        mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
        return new GeometryModel3D(mesh, material);
    }
```

but it doesn't show any line in output?

What is wrong with this?

I know that there are some 3d libraries that can do this easily, but I like to learn how to do it in WPF and then investigate how to do this using libraries (such as helix3d)

Comment: Set your FarClip (`FarPlaneDistance`) higher. It looks like you are clipping your drawings at 10 and draw your lines at about 100. Set it to 1000.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for your suggestion, Tried it without any success: still can not see the line!

Comment: make camera further. `Position="50,0,0" , LookDirection="-1,0,0"` and remove farplane and nearplane distance and up direction. and draw your line at 0. or if you want to position it you must see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690348/make-camera-lookdirection-look-front-face)

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a triangle where two corners are at the same point, that is a triangle with zero area so it can never be seen from any angle. WPF uses only triangles with area

To create a line you must make a rectangle the length and width of the line, and split it with a diagonal to create two narrow triangles. So you need four positions and two triangles, like "0 1 2 0 1 3". Then of course you must make sure that the orientation of this rectangle is so that it is facing the camera.

You can google or bing for helix toolbox which is an excellent library of utilities for 3D in WPF. There you might find a useful helper function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to draw just line. In 3D you usually need triangles. If you have triangle you can determine `normals`. They are used to define facing of triangle which is used in lighting and texturing.

**Camera settings**
Typical camera `Position` is somewhere in positive z coordinates (something like 0, 0, 2 or 5, 0, 20), `LookDirection` vector is 0, 0, -1 and `UpDirection` vector is 0, 1, 0. In this case axes should be positioned as they usually are (positive y axis goes up and positive x axis goes to the right).
If you change `UpDirection` to 1, 0, 0 then positive x axis goes up not y axis.
If you change `Position` to negative z coordinates (0, 0, -5) and `LookDirection` to 0, 0, 1 then you look at your sceen from "behind" so positive x axis goes to the left (not to the right) but y axis still goes up.

In your settings your camera is pointing to the positive y numbers from origin and z axis goes up. X axis still goes to the right. If I add third point to your code. Point 100, 0, 100, than you can see small black triangle.

```
mesh.Positions.Add(startPoint);
mesh.Positions.Add(endPoint);
mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(100, 0, 100));
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
```

This triangle is small because of distance from camera - 100. So as @Samuels says in comment another error in settings is `FarPlaneDistance="10"`.

Answer (score 0):

you're building lines with no thickness....actually this and pixel coloring are the 2 most important problems of WPF....
If you want to draw lines you'll have to build it as a quadrangle (2 connex triangles), if you want to get smarter and have a lower number of triangles you can use other tricks (I'll let you think about it ^^, but for a given mesh you can have a wireframe that has exactly the same number of triangles as your mesh, which would not be the case if you create quadrangles)